# Best way to import different scripts in HTML based on Production or Development

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have been trying to figure out a good way to have a single main page index.html which links to a file that includes my  files to import .js files. These pages cannot be loaded asynchronously. I want to import the .min.js file in production and the normal .js file in development. So what I do is:

```
<head>
    <script src="script1.js"></script>
<head>
<body>
    <div>Do stuff</div>
    <script src="script2.js"></script>
</body>
```

In production script1.js contains:

```
document.write('\
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/.../jquery.min.js"></script>\
    <script other_needed_files.min.js>\
');
```

It's the same in development, just without the .min

Script2 contains the same thing, but it includes things that can be loaded after the content so it's later in the page.

This works. Script1 contains my .js files in development and it contains my min.js files in production, and I have a single index.html that is unchanged between the two. The issue is that Google Chrome doesn't like pulling source with a .write. It gives the warning:

> script1.js:1 A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script,
>   https://ajax.googleapis.com/.../jquery.min.js, is
>   invoked via document.write. This may be blocked by the browser if the
>   device has poor network connectivity.

I read more about it:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write

This makes sense that what I'm doing isn't the best way. I also tried to use:

```
<link rel="import">
```

which appears to be the exact thing I want, but that doesn't work in most browsers other than chrome. I tried the asynchronous loading, but it doesn't work on my page. My only other option is to have two index.html's that I see (One for production, one for development).

Comment: Are domains or subdomains different for the 2 environments? Can you do this using server side language?

Comment: If you aren't doing a client side build process like grunt or gulp, you probably want to look into it. You could then use something like gulp-inject to replace your development styles or scripts with production ones. You also probably want to learn about module loaders/dependency management, e.g. requirejs or systemjs.

Comment: They are different domains. For example I pull angular from google's ajax.googleapis.com. Will Gulp replace it line by line or just swap files? I wanted to avoid using a build process... but I realize this may not be the best solution.

Comment: Did you try with `appendChild` instead of document.write?